# Server 2022 (upgraded from 2012R2) has a blank ServiceUrl for Microsoft.Update.ServiceManager

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-update, windows-server-2022

We have upgraded a couple of servers from Windows Server 2012R2 to Windows Server 2022 without issue. However, we just did one and it will not connect to Windows Update.

We aren't using WSUS just regular Windows Updates direct from Microsoft.

[image: Broken Windows Update]

We've done all the usual troubleshooting steps:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/additional-resources-for-windows-update#reset-windows-update-components-manually
- DISM /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
- SFC /scannow
- Windows Update Troubleshooter

And gone beyond to additional steps:

- https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/24742-reset-windows-update-windows-10-a.html
- https://www.elevenforum.com/t/reset-windows-update-in-windows-11.3808/

I started looking more deeply in one of the ETL files here: C:\Windows\Logs\WindowsUpdate
and it looks like it can't find the Windows Update service:
[image: Missing Windows Update Service]

And if I check via Powershell it seems to show the same -- here is the output from the non-working server:

```
(New-Object -ComObject 'Microsoft.Update.ServiceManager').Services


Name                  : Windows Update
ContentValidationCert : {}
ExpirationDate        : 6/18/5254 9:21:00 PM
IsManaged             : False
IsRegisteredWithAU    : True
IssueDate             : 1/1/2003 12:00:00 AM
OffersWindowsUpdates  : True
RedirectUrls          : System.__ComObject
ServiceID             : 9482f4b4-e343-43b6-b170-9a65bc822c77
IsScanPackageService  : False
CanRegisterWithAU     : True
ServiceUrl            :
SetupPrefix           :
IsDefaultAUService    : True
```

And here is the output from a working upgraded server:

```
(New-Object -ComObject 'Microsoft.Update.ServiceManager').Services


Name                  : DCat Flighting Prod
ContentValidationCert : {}
ExpirationDate        :
IsManaged             : False
IsRegisteredWithAU    : False
IssueDate             : 1/1/1601 12:00:00 AM
OffersWindowsUpdates  : True
RedirectUrls          : System.__ComObject
ServiceID             : 8b24b027-1dee-babb-9a95-3517dfb9c552
IsScanPackageService  : False
CanRegisterWithAU     : False
ServiceUrl            : https://fe3cr.delivery.mp.microsoft.com/
SetupPrefix           : wu
IsDefaultAUService    : False

Name                  : Windows Store (DCat Prod)
ContentValidationCert : {}
ExpirationDate        :
IsManaged             : False
IsRegisteredWithAU    : False
IssueDate             : 1/1/1601 12:00:00 AM
OffersWindowsUpdates  : False
RedirectUrls          : System.__ComObject
ServiceID             : 855e8a7c-ecb4-4ca3-b045-1dfa50104289
IsScanPackageService  : False
CanRegisterWithAU     : True
ServiceUrl            : https://fe3cr.delivery.mp.microsoft.com/
SetupPrefix           : ws
IsDefaultAUService    : False

Name                  : Windows Update
ContentValidationCert : {}
ExpirationDate        :
IsManaged             : False
IsRegisteredWithAU    : True
IssueDate             : 1/1/1601 12:00:00 AM
OffersWindowsUpdates  : True
RedirectUrls          : System.__ComObject
ServiceID             : 9482f4b4-e343-43b6-b170-9a65bc822c77
IsScanPackageService  : False
CanRegisterWithAU     : True
ServiceUrl            : https://fe2cr.update.microsoft.com/v6/
SetupPrefix           : wu
IsDefaultAUService    : True
```

Is there any way to fix the missing/broken registered services and ServiceUrl?

Thank you!